# How to read the ETH value and other token values from an account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js, ether

Let's say I've created an Ethereum account using this code:

```
web3.eth.accounts.create();
> {
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

How do I connect (unlock) to that account later and see all the ETH and other tokens it contains?

Comment: For ERC20 tokens, you will need to call the `balanceOf` function of contract.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I connect (unlock) to that account later and see all the ETH and other tokens it contains?

`eth.accounts` shows you all known accounts. To unlock and see balance of the first one:

```
> personal.lockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
```